# Android How to hide the phone number programmatically

Tags: android, hide, phone-number, phone-call

How can I hide or show my phone number during a call without going into the settings?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement this by using a check box :

```
 <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cb_Show" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
   />
```

_

```
    CheckBox cbShow = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_Show);
TextView text=findViewById(R.id.text);

text.setText("some text to hide");

        cbShow.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked)
                    text.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);
                else
                    text.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

or you can use a toggleButton instead [example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-togglebutton-example/)

good luck